# How To disable a <h:commandButton> in jsf while form gets loading?

Tags: java, jsf

I am developing a web form using jsf. In that i need to disable the  while the form gets loading,then again it wil enable after completing the form loading

Answer (score 3):

Put a `<script>` right after the button which disables it.

```xml
<h:form id="myform">
    <h:commandButton id="mybutton" />
    <script>document.getElementById('myform:mybutton').disabled = true;</script>
```

On `window.onload`, enable it again. It doesn't matter where this script is placed.

```xml
<script>window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('myform:mybutton').disabled = false; }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done only on the client side, with javascript:

- disable it (set "enabled" to false) in a javascript snippet right after the button. Or in fact disabled it at the very start by setting `disabled="true"`
- onload (or at the end of the body) enable it.

Comment: Top of body section? The button element isn't there in the HTML DOM tree then. So `document.getElementById('buttonid').disabled=true;` won't work over there. Over there, you'd basically need to do it onload, but at that point the button doesn't need to be disabled anymore :)